# How to change the next page's heading according to the previous one?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have two HTML pages: on the first one, I have 3 tables with people's names and last names. On the second page, there is one heading. Now on the 1st page, I want to click on tables and according to the table that is clicked on, I want to change the 2nd page's heading text. I know that I have to do it by using innerHTML in JS DOM. Before that, I have a for loop in order to change the page. I don't know how to do it.. (I am a beginner)

My for loop and HTML codes:

```js
for (var i=0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".tab").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".tab")[i].onclick = function () {
              location.href = "headingpage.html";
          };
    };
```

```html
  <body>
    <table class="tab">
      <tr>
        <td class="name">111</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="lastName">111</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="tab">
      <tr>
        <td class="name">222</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="lastName">222</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="tab">
      <tr>
        <td class="name">333</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="lastName">333</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

For example, if I click on Name1, I would like to see the next page's heading as 111.
How can I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: You could **pass** information from one page to another from the **URL** by appending a quesiton mark (`?`). So you could do `location.href = "headingpage.html?name=11&lastname=22"`. For this to work you'll have to be more specific, are you using some kind of server, does the server see  `headingpage.html` the same way as `headingpage.html?name=11`?

Comment: No, I don't use any server. I am using static files

Comment: I'm seeing a pattern of questions, is this a homework problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658989/getting-the-field-value-from-another-page-after-an-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of how to do this. notice in the url bar that we are passing with GET a parameter named idx from the first page to the second page.  Then in the second page we get the parameter with `params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)`:

first page html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
       <title>test</title>
       <style>
           a {
              text-decoration: none;
           }
       </style>
</head>

<body>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td><a href='test2.html?idx=0'>Joe Smith</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a href='test2.html?idx=1'>Lisa Jones</a></td>
      </tr>
</body>

</html>
```

second page html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <title>test2</title>
</head>

<body>
   <h1 id='ohmy'></h1>

   <script>
      const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
      var idx = params.get('idx')          

      var headers = ['Joe Smith', 'Lisa Jones']
      document.getElementById('ohmy').innerHTML = headers[idx]
   </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for do that without a server is not so easy. But you can try a possible solution.

First you have to make some changes to your JS code:

```
let tabInfo; 

for (var i=0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".tab").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".tab")[i].onclick = function () {
              tabInfo = this.innerHTML;
              document.location.href = "headingpage.html";
          };
    };
```

And on your headingpage.html:

```
<h1 class="tabInfo"><h1>
```

Then in the same or on a different JS file:

```
document.querySelector(".tabInfo").innerHTML = tabInfo;
```

Im not sure if it will work. In that case tell me and i will try more hard.

Comment: Thank you for your time I really appreciate it..  But it did not work, instead of Heading there is "undefined" word written

Comment: Ok, i will try to do an example.